# Issue in get token value form dropbox api in codeigniter php

Tags: php, codeigniter, dropbox, dropbox-api, dropbox-php

i want to access token value form dropbox api programmatically

[image]

see above image in that at last there are token value i want to get that token value pragmatically. Right now flow is like below

1. Go to: https://www.dropbox.com/1/oauth2/authorize?locale=&client_id=a6sait9lgzwntkx&response_type=code
2. Click "Allow" (you might have to log in first).
3. Copy the authorization code.

When i perform above steps than above dialog is open but i want to get token value directly so is there any other way for getting that token value ? your all suggestion are appreciable.

Comment: `My Rootways App`? Don't know why you hid the appname from the image, but provided a link to it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you can use a redirect URI, you can get that "authorization code" delivered to your app programmatically. There's a guide about this that should be helpful here:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/oauthguide#oauth-2-on-the-web

When using a redirect URI, supplied via the `redirect_uri` parameter, the authorization code is returned to your specified redirect URI in the `code` parameter after the user authorizes your app. Your app can then exchange the authorization code for an access token.